# Untar an archive without creating missing directories

Tags: tar, archive

I have a tar archive that looks something like this:

```
$ tar -tf archive.tar
foo/
foo/bar.txt
dontcreateme/baz.txt
```

The `foo` directory is directly specified in the archive, but `dontcreateme` is not - only as a parent component of the `baz.txt` file. Despite this, tar automatically creates it while extracting the archive. Is there a way to disable this behavior, and extract the archive without automatically creating the `dontcreateme/` directory? I want the extraction to just fail if it's missing.

I looked through the man page, but wasn't able to find anything relevant.

Edit, more details:  I need to be able to delete every extracted file later (with something like `tar -tf archive.tar | xargs rm -rf`) and don't want to leave extra directories on the filesystem. It's better to have the extraction fail if target directories don't exist for some reason. I can't just include those directories in the archive as well, because if they do exist they might contain other files that shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: I suggest to [edit] the question and add some background information about your use case: Why do you need the extraction to fail if `dontcreateme` does not already exist? What is the purpose of this requirement?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The following doesn't answer your question but may solve your problem... If you extract using the tar `--one-top-level` option with no directory specified, a directory will be created in the current directory with the base name of the archive file ("archive" in your example) and everything will be extracted into that directory. Later, you should be able to delete that directory and all its contents to delete every extracted file and every directory, empty or not, created during extraction.